# No access to local file

Tags: json, angular, angular2-http

I try to test my Angular2 service like this:

**spec.ts file in 'C:/MyAngularApp/src/app/common'**

```
let testFile = "./test.json"; // full path: C:\MyAngularApp\src\app\common\test.json

http.get(testFile).map(d => d.json()).subscribe(()=>log("it works"))
```

But I can't make it work - I got:

> Failed: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9876/test.json

I've tried to put this file in other location:

- "C:\MyAngularApp"
- "C:\MyAngularApp\src"
- "C:\MyAngularApp\src\app"
- "C:\MyAngularApp\src\assets"

But without result.

I believe this is something with the path..

*This is the reason why I want to load local file by http.get:
I want to make some extra layer for my some of my services. I called it "HttpResourse" which contains methods like: Create(), Get(), Update(), Delete() and SetResourceUrl(resourceUrl: string). The last one is the reason why I need to load file by path.*

Comment: Why are you trying to access a file inside the project via HTTP? Why not just import it?

Comment: I want to test MyHttpService so I need to "download" file anyway.

Comment: If you want to test your service use the `MockBackend` as the docs show, then you don't even need to have an internet connection to test.

Comment: MyHttpService contains some extra logic which I want to test on a real json data.

Comment: And the mock backend is perfectly capable of responding with a JSON payload - it can test both the request made and the handling of the response. Please [read the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html).

Comment: Maybe mock backend is a good solution but I still want to know how to load local file to my http service.

Comment: Why? Why do you think you even *can* do that? You could put it in a static folder like assets and access it via localhost, but I'm pretty sure you can't use a relative path and really don't see why you'd want to. If you want to test a service, use the infrastructure provided. If you want to do something else, explain what that is and why. Otherwise it's just a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I added some explanation at the end of my post.
I still want to know why can't I access local file. Maybe it's security reason?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer!

when I set path to "assets/test.json" all works fine. It can not be "pathToSrc/assets/test.json" or anything like that. It must be "assets" or "./assets".

But why? Why this directory ("assets") is so special?

Comment: relative paths are not relative to the root by default.  If you want 'pathToSrc/assets/test.json' to work, which is relative to root, you can add a <base href="/"> tag to your HTML page, within <header>